# $T^2$ has a cyclic vector

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear operator $T$ on a vector space $V$ is said to have a cyclic vector $v$ if the set $\{T^k\,v\}$ for $k\geq 0$ is a spanning set of $V$. I am trying to prove that if $T^2$ has a cyclic vector then so does $T$. Can anyone help me with a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\{T^{2n}(v)\}$ is a subset of $\{T^n(v)\}$.

Comment: Thanks, I was being a bit silly tying to prove the first $dim (V)$ powers formed a basis.

Comment: Is the converse true? If T has cyclic vector does T^2 automatically also have cyclic vector?

Comment: @AbhigyanSaha No.  Let $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ be a basis for a vector space.  Then the permutation transformation $T(v_1) = v_2$, $T(v_2) = v_3$, $T(v_3) = v_4$, and $T(v_4) = v_1$ has a cyclic vector $v_1$.  But, the even powers of $T$ won't have a cyclic vector.